# R: How to use rvest or any R package to extract certain elements from tag's attribute?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have used the `xml2::read_html` function to read the below string (simplified from real example).

```
<table>
<tobody>
<tr>
<td width=\"71\"><a href=\"JavaScript:gibo_load('http://something.com/XYZW');\">
hello
</td>
</tr>
</tobody>
</table>
```

`rvest::html_table(x)` is able to create a table from it that looks like

if I set `x` to be the above HTML as a string/characters

```
x1
hello
```

But I wish to extract the URL which is part of the `<a>` tag's `href` attribute.

But `rvest::html_attrs(x)` doesn't seem to work. What's the way to extract attributes from tags using rvest of any other R package?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the links from the nodes, one must first obtain a vector of nodes and then pass the vector to `html_attr()` with the appropriate tag identified.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

page<- read_html("<table>
<tobody>
<tr>
<td width=\"71\"><a href=\"JavaScript:gibo_load('http://something.com/XYZW');\">
hello
</td>
</tr>
</tobody>
</table>")


#create a vector of nodes with the links
linknodes <- page %>% html_nodes("a")
#extract the href attribute.
answer <-linknodes %>% html_attr("href")
answer
#[1] "JavaScript:gibo_load('http://something.com/XYZW');"
```

In this example the "JavaScript:..." was a part of the href attribute.
If you are only interested in the "http:..." part then you will need to use `gsub` or `str_extract` to obtain the final result.